# Изменение вида родителя при :checked

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте,

Есть разметка

```
<label class='radioConainer'><input type='radio' name='name' value='1' checked></label>
<label class='radioConainer'><input type='radio' name='name' value='2'></label>
<label class='radioConainer'><input type='radio' name='name' value='3'></label>
```

CSS:

```
.radioContainer {
    border: 1px solid #258eff;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Как в зависимости от свойства :checked изменить цвет рамки у родительского label без использования JS?

Comment: Есть селекторы, которые, скажем, сделают следующий рядом стоящий элемент каким-то другим, к примеру, input:checked+label или все последующие  input:checked~label, но чтобы предыдущие или родителей, по-моему, еще нету такого.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wr81f2wz/

Comment: @undestroyer, ждите css4, там будет такой селектор. @soledar10, странный ответ, который совершенно не относится к вопросу

Comment: @MasterAlex откуда у вас такая информация о CSS4? Насколько я знаю, такие селекторы не будут реализованы

Comment: @MasterAlex не так понял вопрос

Comment: @inferusvv, насколько я понял, там будет даже несколько вариантов, например, можно будет обратиться напрямую к parent: `CSS4 let us target a parent element using A! > B` (копировано [отсюда][1]), а также появится селектор :has(), который на данный момент работает только в jquery, но он позволил бы решить данную задачу автору.

[1]: http://www.script-tutorials.com/css4-selectors-level-4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент с помощью CSS нельзя "достучаться" до родительского элемента относительно текущего

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](http://web-standards.ru/articles/parent-selector/) ответ почему доступ вверх в CSS невозможен.
[Это](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#overview) черновик CSS четвёртой версии, там есть доступ к родителю.
Правда пока он предполагается быть медленным, но при выпуске бэты, наверняка, это исправят.